# How to do proper user authorization using Deezer Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, authorization, deezer, amazon-fire-tv

I'm currently using the Deezel Android SDK to use audio playback for my FireTV. When trying to authorize users I keep getting an `W/System.err: com.deezer.sdk.network.connect.event.DialogError: Invalid SSL certificate received (SSL error: 3)` error.

Am I doing something incorrectly? I'm using DeezerConnect to authorize users but the webview that shows up goes away after .5 seconds.
Here's my code:

```
    private String applicationID = "123456";
    private Activity activity;
    private DeezerConnect deezerConnect;

    public DeezerMusicManager(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
        deezerConnect = new DeezerConnect(activity, applicationID);
    }

    public void init(){
        String[] permissions = new String[]{
                Permissions.BASIC_ACCESS,
                Permissions.MANAGE_LIBRARY,
                Permissions.LISTENING_HISTORY
        };



        /**Listener for authentication events*/
        DialogListener listener = new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle bundle) {
                SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();
                sessionStore.save(deezerConnect, activity.getApplicationContext());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "LogIn Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "LogIn Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("DEEZERERROR",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        };
        deezerConnect.authorize(activity, permissions,listener);
    }
}
```